# Instance group with nvme attached on google cloud platform

Tags: linux-networking, google-cloud-platform, multiple-instances

I understand that the local SDD (nvme) can only be added when the instance is launched.

The problem is that we need to have a fast system of cache and it would be useful to be able to scale instances with nvme attached. Meaning  that, we want to have an instance group that is able to scale and launch instances with the local SSD (nvme) attached.

In our plans we would be able to create an iso/template with the configuration and apply to an instance group with nvme in order to have our preconfigured machines scaling.

Is this possible some how ?

Comment: We run nvme based instances in AWS. We don't autoscale, but we do have an automatic provisioning process. We use Saltstack during this process to make sure the nvme drives are present and formatted before putting data on them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do this using [Instance Templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates), which are pre-determined templates for your instances, and [Managed Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances), which can scale depending on certain metrics.

Comment: The template must be created using the beta flag "--local-ssd" from the [CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-templates/create). At the moment the feature is still in beta and the Cloud Console does not supports it.